# QML/C++ coloring every 8th character in a QString

Tags: c++, qml

I am making a converter to convert a string to binary and I want to change the color of every 8th character of the resulting binary conversion result to red to symbolize the beginning of each ascii character. The user enters a string a text input and the converted result is displayed in a text area like so:

[image: pic]

Every 8th 0 or 1 should be red.

I'm not sure where to begin and is this even possible? And if I were to reverse the converter (user enters binary and its converted to ascii characters) could it still work? Thanks.

Edit:

I am adding `"<font color='red'>" and "</font>"` to the beginning and end of every eighth binary digit but the result displayed is literally `"<font color='red'>0</font>"`, it is not applying the html styling. 
My TextInput sets the TextArea.text whenever the user types using a C++ function.

```
TextInput {     
...
    onTextChanged: {
        uiText.setBinaryString(myTextInput.text)
        myTextAreaText.text = uiText.getBinaryString()
    }
}
```

C++ functions

```
void UITextConnector::setBinaryString(QString s)
{
    binaryString = convertToBinary(s);
}

QString UITextConnector::getBinaryString()
{
    return binaryString;
}


QString UITextConnector::convertToBinary(QString qs)
{

    std::string resultString;

    if (binaryMode) {
        std::string qStringConverted = qs.toStdString();
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < qStringConverted.size(); i++) {
            std::bitset<8> b(qStringConverted.c_str()[i]);
            std::string nextBinary = b.to_string();
            nextBinary = "<font color='#00AA00'>" + nextBinary.substr(0,1) + "</font>" + nextBinary.substr(1);
            resultString += nextBinary;
        }
    } else {

        std::string qStringConverted = qs.toStdString();
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < qStringConverted.size() ; i = i + 8) {
           resultString += UITextConnector::strToChar(qStringConverted.substr(i, i+8).c_str());
        }
    }
    return QString::fromStdString(resultString);
}
```

However, this only works if I use a label but not when I use a textArea.

Comment: TextInput doesn't support rich text, use TextEdit instead

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any source or whatever it is too difficult to understand what is your fail. Anyway, I would do that in the following way:

```
TextArea {
    id: txt
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 10
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    text: ""
    function setText(str)
    {
        var arr = str.match(/.{1,8}/g) || [];
        var result = "";
        for(var index in arr)
        {
           result += "<font color='red'>" + arr[index].substring(0, 1) + "</font>" + arr[index].substring(1);
        }
        txt.text = result;
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        txt.setText("aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddd");
    }
}
```